I'm trying to understand how the stack works
I'm trying to understand how the stack works and I have the following question that I would like to solve: after having analyzed the execution of the arm32 assembly code from the first line, assuming that the top of the stack is initially located at the address 0x00000000, what will be the value contained in sp at the execution of the statement on line 9?


0x00000000  2) 0xFFFFFFF8  3) 0xFFFFFFFC


The code is this:
1) start bl subroutine1 
2) end
3) subroutine1 str lr, [sp, #−4]!
4) mov r0,#2
5) mov r1,#4
6) bl subroutine2
7) ldr pc,[sp],#4
8) subroutine2 lr, [sp, #−4]!
9) cmp r0,#0
10) beq subroutine2_end 
11) mov r2,r0
12) mov r0,#0
13) loop add r0, r0, r1, lsl #1
14) subs r2, r2, #1
15) bne loop
16) subroutine2_end ldr pc, [sp], #4

I tried to think in two ways: the first concerns the fact that the sp should be a preserved register and consequently since there are subroutines these must not alter it. So the value should be 0x00000000.
If I think about how to decrease the stack, however, I know that I have to decrease by a multiple of 4 and it certainly would not be a value that is reported as among the following answers.
I hope I was clear and that someone can provide me with an explanation.
Thank you

Which one is supposed to be line 9? Note that all the answers are multiples of 4. If it's line 9 as marked then line 6 decreased sp by 4 to 0xFFFFFFFC.

It sounds like you may be confused by negative numbers. What's -4 in hex, on arm32?

Hi @Jester, the line 9 is the compare -> cmp r0,#0. If the value result is 0xFFFFFFFC how can I calculate it?

By that time line 8 has done another -4 so the result is -8 which is 0xFFFFFFF8 (because 0xFFFFFFF8 + 8 = (1)00000000)


the first concerns the fact that the sp should be a preserved register and consequently since there are subroutines these must not alter it. So the value should be 0x00000000.

If we were speaking about line 2 this analysis would be correct.  From the point of view of one subroutine/function the call-preserved registers must hold the same values after return from a call (line 2) as they had at the time the call is made (line 1).
However, subroutines are allowed to modify call-preserved registers — they simply have to restore the original incoming value before returning to their callers.  Function calling suspends the caller, and activates the callee.  Since the caller is suspended, it does not uses the call-preserved registers during the callee's execution; it won't notice if preserved registers are temporarily changed, as long as their values are returned to original at such time when the caller resumes.
In the case of most call-preserved registers that is accomplished by saving on the stack upon function entry & restoring later as part of function exit.  This is because the called function doesn't have any clue as to what value is in that those registers, so this is the only reasonable way to restore their original values.
In the case of the stack pointer, because we know that register has meaning upon entry to a function, namely demarking the free area of the stack, for functions to temporarily claim, use, and release, there are several ways that the necessary preservation of its incoming value can be accomplished:

by not modifying it at all

by subtracting a constant from it upon entry and adding that same constant upon return, the stack pointer is restored, hile  an adjusted value is used by the called function for access to local stack storage.  This is commonly seen approach, and is what your sample code snippet is doing.

by using a frame pointer register to hold a copy of the incoming stack pointer value (upon entry), and copying the frame pointer back to the stack pointer on exit (note that the frame pointer register itself is call-preserved, so it must be saved on the stack and restored on exit).


So, at line 9, the stack pointer register should reflect the pushes that have occurred in getting to that line.
Lines 3 and 8 each push a word onto the stack.  These pushes claim stack space by decrementing the stack pointer by 4, or adding -4, same thing.  One of the three choices is correct.
